# Short story about a man and a boy waking up and being the only people in the world

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Read this s years ago in a sci-fi anthology. A man and boy are the only people left in the world. I think they travel around on a train. And it may be by Ray Bradbury but I’ve never been able to identify it from searching so it may not be. Anyone have any ideas?